# Writing extended attributes to files on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, metadata, extended-properties

I am trying to use the `setfattr` command in the command line, but it tells me `command not found`. I'm assuming this means that the package is not installed, however from what I understand OSX should have extended attributes enabled by default. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such command as `setfattr`.  Maybe that's a typo for `setxattr` or `fsetxattr`, but those aren't commands either, they are C APIs.  The command you want is `xattr`.

Comment: It really doesn't exist? Here it says it's a Linux command http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/setfattr.htm oh well, thank you for the correction though

Comment: @kag359six, Mac OS X is based on FreeBSD, not Linux.